# Using the robot framework in python

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Is it possible to use the Robot Framework programmatically in python?  All I find are resources on using Java.

Comment: can you expand a bit more on what you're really trying to do? Are you trying to write python code that creates test suites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use robot framework programmatically, if by that you're asking if you can create and run test suites written purely in python. When you do that, you're missing the point of robot framework.

To see how to do it, read the [robot framework API documentation](http://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/2.8.1/autodoc/robot.running.html). Here is an example:

```
from robot.api import TestSuite

suite = TestSuite('Activate Skynet')
suite.imports.library('OperatingSystem')
test = suite.tests.create('Should Activate Skynet', tags=['smoke'])
test.keywords.create('Set Environment Variable', args=['SKYNET', 'activated'], type='setup')
test.keywords.create('Environment Variable Should Be Set', args=['SKYNET'])
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are understand what Robot Framework exactly does.
Robot Framework is build on Python and if you like you can use it within Java by a Maven plugin. Because of speed issues the preferred way is to use it directly on python.

[See the Quick start for more information](https://github.com/robotframework/QuickStartGuide/blob/master/QuickStart.rst)